# enabling module error in vendor after installing with composer by CLI

Tags: magento2, module, composer, linux, enable-disable

I add a module with composer and then try to enable it by writing the command `php bin/magento module:enable SR_UnicodeUrl`
but I get a long error in response that starts with this phrase

> Unknown package has no name defined

and it continues a long term (below image)
[image]

and it finished with this

[image]

how should I resolve this problem?
(my magento runs in docker image in Linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to install braintree module first and then also need to have a custom module installed SR_UnicodeUrl in your app/code folder where SR is vendor name and UnicodeUrl is module name, try to find the already built module from github then install that and then try to enable it.

Comment: I can not command with CLI even one line. for any command that I write it shows me error (first image). it works on my windows but when it goes on Linux it doesn't do correctly

Comment: you said - you added a module with composer , I want , just try to add module manually .. do the copy paste of module .. don't use composer then try again.

Comment: yes, I am working on it . but is this a good way to cut the module folder in vendor to app/code in Magento? if I do this process there is no need for the CLI command ? and module enables itself(cause it exists on app/code)? thanks a lot for your guidance

Comment: thanks . it works at last.